# How to import Python Class or Function from parent directory?

Tags: python

I have this project structure,

```
.\src
  .\api
    test.py
  .\config
    config.py
  app.py
```

when i'm trying to import a function or class from `test.py` inside `config.py`, using this statement

`from src.api.test import tes_func`

I get this error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.api'`

if i use these 2 lines i can import using

`from api.test import tes_func`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

why it's not working when use `from src.api.test import test_func`
Is there a way to import python files without  `sys.path.append("../")`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no package named `src`, at least not in the search path used by `src/app.py`. With this directory structure, just use `from api.text import test_func`, then make sure that the package `api` appears in the search path used by `app.py` (Or equivalently, make sure `app.py` is executed in an environment where the directory containing the `api` package is on the search path.)

Comment: @chepner, thanks for the idea, but why no package named `src`, it's already there right ?

Comment: There's a directory named `src`; that's not the same as a package. The *contents* of `src` are potential modules and packages available to `app.py`, but not `src` itself. When you add `../` to the search path, then `src`, being a directory in `..`, is visible as a package.

Comment: You have a script `app.py` and two packages `api` and `config` that should be packaged so that you can install them in a virtual environment, so that `app.py` doesn't need to be responsible for augmenting its search path: instead, everything it needs will be in a directory already *on* its search path.

Comment: Also, you only needed to add `..` to the search path *or* changing the import to `from api.test import ...`; `api` is already visible to `app.py`, being in the same directory.

Comment: great, it's same for the `config.py` right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the working directory.
Before python was only able to see other files inside the config folder.
If you run your program from a common parent directory python is able to see both folders and there files.

```
 ..\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> python -m src.config.config
```

My folder structure:

[image]

With this command src is now your root directory meaning in `config.py` you will need to import the function like this:

```
from src.api.test import tes_func
```